# How to right to left text in for loop?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have:

CSS:

```
.p1
    {
        direction:rtl;
        text-align:right;
        float:right;
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="p1">
    @{
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "../home/index/" + i);
        }
    }
</div>
```

Output is: 1 2 3 4 5

but i want : 5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
 <span>
    @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "../home/index/" + i)
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<bdi>` tag
not cross browser but helpful
good luck